# NotePad++ regex remove words with space and certain letters

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, notepad

I'm trying to remove words that feature a "com" and ends with a ".". I would like to remove the full word and leave the "."

Here is an example of the starting text:

```
This is a test testcom.
```

I would like the output to be:

```
This is a test .
```

What I have come up with so far is:

```
(?<=\ ).*?com(?=\.)
```

but this seems to highlight the full sentence to the first space.

Comment: `\w+com`  replace with `nothing `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<=\ ).*?com(?=\.)` pattern matches a location after a space, then matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars but as few as possible up to the first occurrence of `com` followed with a dot. So, it will match any amount of spaces on its way from the matched location after space to the `com.` substring.

**If `com` can be anywhere inside the word** you may use either of the two expressions below:

```
[^\s.]*com[^\s.]*\.
\w*com\w*\.
```

and replace with a  `.`.

Or, equivalent:

```
[^\s.]*com[^\s.]*(?=\.)
\w*com\w*(?=\.)
```

and replace with an empty string.

**If the `com` must be at the end of the word**, just remove the second `[^\s.]*` / `\w*` from the above expressions.

**Details**

- `[^\s.]*com[^\s.]*\.` - matches 0+ chars other than whitespace and `.`, then `com` and then again 0+ chars other than whitespace and `.` and  a `.`
- `\w*com\w*\.` - matches 0+ letters/digits/`_`, then `com`, then again 0+ letters/digits/`_` and then `.`.

Notepad++ demo and settings:

[image]

Comment: This Works Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this one will suit you:

```
\w*?com(?=\.)
```